# NSScrollView: overriding scrollWheel method breaks trackpad panning

Tags: macos, macos-sierra, appkit, nsscrollview

I have a subclass of NSScrollView, like so:

```
class ImageScrollView : NSScrollView {
    override func scrollWheel(with event: NSEvent) {
        super.scrollWheel(with:event)
    }
}
```

As you can see, the only thing this does is override the scrollWheel: method and call super.

The issue I'm having is that as soon as I do this, using 2 fingers on the trackpad to try to pan around the scroll view when zoomed in stops working.  Removing the overridden method fixes it.  Any tips?

Comment: I found this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31186430/scrolling-in-nsscrollview-stops-when-overwriting-scrollwheel-function. Seems to be a bug in interface builder - both "show horizontal scroller" and "show vertical scroller" need to be checked. Either way, the scrollview will lose the ability for responsive scroll.