# NSScrollView subclass doesn't scroll

Tags: swift, macos, subclass, nsscrollview

I'm making a macOS app and i have created a simple NSScrollView subclass. However, the scrollview doesn't scroll.

When i set the property NSScrollView.hasHorizontalScroller or the property NSScrollView.hasVerticalScroller to true,
then the scrolling works. But i want the scrollbars to be hidden, so these properties will be set to false.

This is my swift (playground) code:

```
import Cocoa
import PlaygroundSupport

class MyScrollView: NSScrollView {

    override init(frame frameRect: NSRect) {
        super.init(frame: frameRect)
    }

    required init?(coder: NSCoder) {
        super.init(coder: coder)
        // fatalError("init(coder:) has not been implemented")
    }

    override func draw(_ dirtyRect: NSRect) {
        super.draw(dirtyRect)

        // Drawing code here.
    }
}

let scrollView = MyScrollView(frame: NSRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: 480, height: 240))
    // scrollView.hasHorizontalScroller = true

// Image of 1280 x 854.
let img = NSImage(byReferencing: URL(fileURLWithPath: "/users/username/Pictures/some-image.jpg"))
let imgView = NSImageView(frame: NSRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: img.size.width, height: img.size.height))
    imgView.image = img

scrollView.documentView = imgView

PlaygroundPage.current.liveView = scrollView
```

I have compared many properties with a normal NSScrollView, but i can't figure it out.
What am i doing wrong?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: What happens when you remove the override of `draw(_:)`? Related question: [Scrolling in NSScrollView stops when overwriting scrollWheel function](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31186430/scrolling-in-nsscrollview-stops-when-overwriting-scrollwheel-function/31201614#31201614).

Comment: Thank you for your answer. If i remove the override of the `draw(_:)` method then the scrolling does indeed work. But i don't really understand why it then works again? 
I thought that calling the super implementation of an overriden method should at least inherit you the superclass functionality. Looking at the related question does this mean that this is also a bug?

Comment: `NSScrollView` (and other Appkit classes) is old and modified and supports old and new behaviours. It checks if some methods are implemented and tries to behave in a compatible way with old code.